# EventBrite APi methods

Tags: eventbrite

[I am trying to use this url for the event attendee information](https://www.eventbrite.com/xml/event_list_attendees?app_key=value&id=3135062055)
I am not getting full details of the *attendee*, but response contains the *attendee id* only

```
<attendees>
   <attendee>
    <event_id>3135062055</event_id>
     <id>110210217</id>
</attendee>

<attendee>
<event_id>3135062055</event_id>
<id>110216615</id>
</attendee>
</attendees>
```

but in the doc I can see the full repose!
what parameters I need to add for this one to get a full attendees information and also
I want to get all the attendees info in one shot itself ?

please help me  to achieve above.
Thanks in advance,

Venkatesh

Answer (score 1):

If you have authorized [Eventbrite's API docs](http://developer.eventbrite.com/) to access your account, then your [user-authentication credentials](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/authentication/) will automatically be added to any requests that you make using the documentation's 'Try it Now' feature.

If you add a [user_key, or Oauth2.0 access_token](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/authentication/) to the request, then you should be able to successfully access your [attendee information](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_list_attendees/).

Your other option is to configure your event to have a [public attendee list](http://www.eventbrite.com/t/how-to-show-attendee-list).  This would allow any attendee information that is publicly visible on your event page to be available via the API URL that you shared (without requiring you to add your private authentication tokens).  Make sure that you reserve the use of this feature for events where the attendees are comfortable disclosing this info.